# Why does regex matching with special unicode characters return different results between browsers on OS X?

Tags: javascript, regex, macos, phantomjs

Note: This question revolves around the library [Autolinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js) but should be generally applicable.

### The Problem

Autolinker uses a regex to match certain parts of URL strings or HTML strings containing URLs. The bulk of this regex revolves around this string:

```
Source: https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js/blob/master/src/RegexLib.js#L14-L29

/**
 * The string form of a regular expression that would match all of the
 * alphabetic ("letter") chars in the unicode character set when placed in a
 * RegExp character class (`[]`). This includes all international alphabetic
 * characters.
 *
 * These would be the characters matched by unicode regex engines `\p{L}`
 * escape ("all letters").
 *
 * Taken from the XRegExp library: http://xregexp.com/
 * Specifically: http://xregexp.com/v/3.0.0/unicode-categories.js
 *
 * @private
 * @type {String}
 */
var alphaCharsStr = 'A-Za-z\\xAA\\xB5\\xBA\\xC0-\\xD6\\xD8-\\xF6\\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B4\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AD\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9EF\uA9FA-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC';
```

This string is used in a regex built with `RegExp`. When using this library in a production application, it was discovered that in Chrome on OS X, URLs containing katakana with dakuten characters were not being parsed correctly.

An example URL: `https://website.com/files/name-ボ.pdf`

You can see the URL failing to be parsed on Autolinker's live example at http://gregjacobs.github.io/Autolinker.js/examples/live-example/. Try using these two examples in the textarea:

```
https://website.com/files/name-ホ.pdf
https://website.com/files/name-ボ.pdf
```

You'll see this result (in Chrome on OS X):

[image: The bug]

### Investigation

I cloned Autolinker to try and find the cause of the bug and add a fix. However, when adding this test case:

```
it( 'should match katakana with dakuten characters', function() {
    var matches = matcher.parseMatches( 'https://test.com/files/file-ボ.pdf' );
    expect( matches.length ).toBe( 1 );
    MatchChecker.expectUrlMatch( matches[ 0 ], 'https://test.com/files/file-ボ.pdf', 0);
} );
```

I found that the test actually passed with no additional modifications to the code. This led to testing in other browsers and on Windows, and here was the resulting compatibility chart:

[image: Compatibility chart]

### Question

Why is it that a regex created with RegExp containing special unicode characters would succeed in some browsers on some operating systems but not others?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but `ボ` is actually two chars, the one you'd want is `ボ`.

Comment: Yeah, the example I'm using was how it was provided to us by a customer. Normalizing these characters could be a good solution, but you'd figure that these non-normalized cases should be handled too

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: That's not a modern unicode regex. That's an old "basic unicode only and it's probably broken" regex. If you want a modern ES6+ regex you'll want to use `/.../u` and then use `[\u{...}-\u{...}]` ranges of character classes to cover all those printable characters. Also, the name of that var doesn't make any sense: most of the characters in that sequence are not alphanumeric, because they're not Latin (in the Unicode sense) characters.

Comment: The example from the live example fails for me in chrome on windows 10 as well

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's very good to know - I'll try messing with the regex

Comment: For international unicode in regular expressions, I have found [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to be an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 3):

A shot in the dark.

Don't use the Unicode characters in the character class.
Instead, try using the `\uXXXX` notation for them.

```
var alphaCharsStr = "A-Za-z\\u00aa\\u00b5\\u00ba\\u00c0-\\u00d6\\u00d8-\\u00f6\\u00f8-\\u02c1\\u02c6-\\u02d1\\u02e0-\\u02e4\\u02ec\\u02ee\\u0370-\\u0374\\u0376\\u0377\\u037a-\\u037d\\u037f\\u0386\\u0388-\\u038a\\u038c\\u038e-\\u03a1\\u03a3-\\u03f5\\u03f7-\\u0481\\u048a-\\u052f\\u0531-\\u0556\\u0559\\u0561-\\u0587\\u05d0-\\u05ea\\u05f0-\\u05f2\\u0620-\\u064a\\u066e\\u066f\\u0671-\\u06d3\\u06d5\\u06e5\\u06e6\\u06ee\\u06ef\\u06fa-\\u06fc\\u06ff\\u0710\\u0712-\\u072f\\u074d-\\u07a5\\u07b1\\u07ca-\\u07ea\\u07f4\\u07f5\\u07fa\\u0800-\\u0815\\u081a\\u0824\\u0828\\u0840-\\u0858\\u08a0-\\u08b4\\u0904-\\u0939\\u093d\\u0950\\u0958-\\u0961\\u0971-\\u0980\\u0985-\\u098c\\u098f\\u0990\\u0993-\\u09a8\\u09aa-\\u09b0\\u09b2\\u09b6-\\u09b9\\u09bd\\u09ce\\u09dc\\u09dd\\u09df-\\u09e1\\u09f0\\u09f1\\u0a05-\\u0a0a\\u0a0f\\u0a10\\u0a13-\\u0a28\\u0a2a-\\u0a30\\u0a32\\u0a33\\u0a35\\u0a36\\u0a38\\u0a39\\u0a59-\\u0a5c\\u0a5e\\u0a72-\\u0a74\\u0a85-\\u0a8d\\u0a8f-\\u0a91\\u0a93-\\u0aa8\\u0aaa-\\u0ab0\\u0ab2\\u0ab3\\u0ab5-\\u0ab9\\u0abd\\u0ad0\\u0ae0\\u0ae1\\u0af9\\u0b05-\\u0b0c\\u0b0f\\u0b10\\u0b13-\\u0b28\\u0b2a-\\u0b30\\u0b32\\u0b33\\u0b35-\\u0b39\\u0b3d\\u0b5c\\u0b5d\\u0b5f-\\u0b61\\u0b71\\u0b83\\u0b85-\\u0b8a\\u0b8e-\\u0b90\\u0b92-\\u0b95\\u0b99\\u0b9a\\u0b9c\\u0b9e\\u0b9f\\u0ba3\\u0ba4\\u0ba8-\\u0baa\\u0bae-\\u0bb9\\u0bd0\\u0c05-\\u0c0c\\u0c0e-\\u0c10\\u0c12-\\u0c28\\u0c2a-\\u0c39\\u0c3d\\u0c58-\\u0c5a\\u0c60\\u0c61\\u0c85-\\u0c8c\\u0c8e-\\u0c90\\u0c92-\\u0ca8\\u0caa-\\u0cb3\\u0cb5-\\u0cb9\\u0cbd\\u0cde\\u0ce0\\u0ce1\\u0cf1\\u0cf2\\u0d05-\\u0d0c\\u0d0e-\\u0d10\\u0d12-\\u0d3a\\u0d3d\\u0d4e\\u0d5f-\\u0d61\\u0d7a-\\u0d7f\\u0d85-\\u0d96\\u0d9a-\\u0db1\\u0db3-\\u0dbb\\u0dbd\\u0dc0-\\u0dc6\\u0e01-\\u0e30\\u0e32\\u0e33\\u0e40-\\u0e46\\u0e81\\u0e82\\u0e84\\u0e87\\u0e88\\u0e8a\\u0e8d\\u0e94-\\u0e97\\u0e99-\\u0e9f\\u0ea1-\\u0ea3\\u0ea5\\u0ea7\\u0eaa\\u0eab\\u0ead-\\u0eb0\\u0eb2\\u0eb3\\u0ebd\\u0ec0-\\u0ec4\\u0ec6\\u0edc-\\u0edf\\u0f00\\u0f40-\\u0f47\\u0f49-\\u0f6c\\u0f88-\\u0f8c\\u1000-\\u102a\\u103f\\u1050-\\u1055\\u105a-\\u105d\\u1061\\u1065\\u1066\\u106e-\\u1070\\u1075-\\u1081\\u108e\\u10a0-\\u10c5\\u10c7\\u10cd\\u10d0-\\u10fa\\u10fc-\\u1248\\u124a-\\u124d\\u1250-\\u1256\\u1258\\u125a-\\u125d\\u1260-\\u1288\\u128a-\\u128d\\u1290-\\u12b0\\u12b2-\\u12b5\\u12b8-\\u12be\\u12c0\\u12c2-\\u12c5\\u12c8-\\u12d6\\u12d8-\\u1310\\u1312-\\u1315\\u1318-\\u135a\\u1380-\\u138f\\u13a0-\\u13f5\\u13f8-\\u13fd\\u1401-\\u166c\\u166f-\\u167f\\u1681-\\u169a\\u16a0-\\u16ea\\u16f1-\\u16f8\\u1700-\\u170c\\u170e-\\u1711\\u1720-\\u1731\\u1740-\\u1751\\u1760-\\u176c\\u176e-\\u1770\\u1780-\\u17b3\\u17d7\\u17dc\\u1820-\\u1877\\u1880-\\u18a8\\u18aa\\u18b0-\\u18f5\\u1900-\\u191e\\u1950-\\u196d\\u1970-\\u1974\\u1980-\\u19ab\\u19b0-\\u19c9\\u1a00-\\u1a16\\u1a20-\\u1a54\\u1aa7\\u1b05-\\u1b33\\u1b45-\\u1b4b\\u1b83-\\u1ba0\\u1bae\\u1baf\\u1bba-\\u1be5\\u1c00-\\u1c23\\u1c4d-\\u1c4f\\u1c5a-\\u1c7d\\u1ce9-\\u1cec\\u1cee-\\u1cf1\\u1cf5\\u1cf6\\u1d00-\\u1dbf\\u1e00-\\u1f15\\u1f18-\\u1f1d\\u1f20-\\u1f45\\u1f48-\\u1f4d\\u1f50-\\u1f57\\u1f59\\u1f5b\\u1f5d\\u1f5f-\\u1f7d\\u1f80-\\u1fb4\\u1fb6-\\u1fbc\\u1fbe\\u1fc2-\\u1fc4\\u1fc6-\\u1fcc\\u1fd0-\\u1fd3\\u1fd6-\\u1fdb\\u1fe0-\\u1fec\\u1ff2-\\u1ff4\\u1ff6-\\u1ffc\\u2071\\u207f\\u2090-\\u209c\\u2102\\u2107\\u210a-\\u2113\\u2115\\u2119-\\u211d\\u2124\\u2126\\u2128\\u212a-\\u212d\\u212f-\\u2139\\u213c-\\u213f\\u2145-\\u2149\\u214e\\u2183\\u2184\\u2c00-\\u2c2e\\u2c30-\\u2c5e\\u2c60-\\u2ce4\\u2ceb-\\u2cee\\u2cf2\\u2cf3\\u2d00-\\u2d25\\u2d27\\u2d2d\\u2d30-\\u2d67\\u2d6f\\u2d80-\\u2d96\\u2da0-\\u2da6\\u2da8-\\u2dae\\u2db0-\\u2db6\\u2db8-\\u2dbe\\u2dc0-\\u2dc6\\u2dc8-\\u2dce\\u2dd0-\\u2dd6\\u2dd8-\\u2dde\\u2e2f\\u3005\\u3006\\u3031-\\u3035\\u303b\\u303c\\u3041-\\u3096\\u309d-\\u309f\\u30a1-\\u30fa\\u30fc-\\u30ff\\u3105-\\u312d\\u3131-\\u318e\\u31a0-\\u31ba\\u31f0-\\u31ff\\u3400-\\u4db5\\u4e00-\\u9fd5\\ua000-\\ua48c\\ua4d0-\\ua4fd\\ua500-\\ua60c\\ua610-\\ua61f\\ua62a\\ua62b\\ua640-\\ua66e\\ua67f-\\ua69d\\ua6a0-\\ua6e5\\ua717-\\ua71f\\ua722-\\ua788\\ua78b-\\ua7ad\\ua7b0-\\ua7b7\\ua7f7-\\ua801\\ua803-\\ua805\\ua807-\\ua80a\\ua80c-\\ua822\\ua840-\\ua873\\ua882-\\ua8b3\\ua8f2-\\ua8f7\\ua8fb\\ua8fd\\ua90a-\\ua925\\ua930-\\ua946\\ua960-\\ua97c\\ua984-\\ua9b2\\ua9cf\\ua9e0-\\ua9e4\\ua9e6-\\ua9ef\\ua9fa-\\ua9fe\\uaa00-\\uaa28\\uaa40-\\uaa42\\uaa44-\\uaa4b\\uaa60-\\uaa76\\uaa7a\\uaa7e-\\uaaaf\\uaab1\\uaab5\\uaab6\\uaab9-\\uaabd\\uaac0\\uaac2\\uaadb-\\uaadd\\uaae0-\\uaaea\\uaaf2-\\uaaf4\\uab01-\\uab06\\uab09-\\uab0e\\uab11-\\uab16\\uab20-\\uab26\\uab28-\\uab2e\\uab30-\\uab5a\\uab5c-\\uab65\\uab70-\\uabe2\\uac00-\\ud7a3\\ud7b0-\\ud7c6\\ud7cb-\\ud7fb\\uf900-\\ufa6d\\ufa70-\\ufad9\\ufb00-\\ufb06\\ufb13-\\ufb17\\ufb1d\\ufb1f-\\ufb28\\ufb2a-\\ufb36\\ufb38-\\ufb3c\\ufb3e\\ufb40\\ufb41\\ufb43\\ufb44\\ufb46-\\ufbb1\\ufbd3-\\ufd3d\\ufd50-\\ufd8f\\ufd92-\\ufdc7\\ufdf0-\\ufdfb\\ufe70-\\ufe74\\ufe76-\\ufefc\\uff21-\\uff3a\\uff41-\\uff5a\\uff66-\\uffbe\\uffc2-\\uffc7\\uffca-\\uffcf\\uffd2-\\uffd7\\uffda-\\uffdc";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I haven't had a chance to look into this, but I'll send the bounty your way since it's going to expire.